# How can I bind the SelectedItemValue from a TreeView back to a ViewModel in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a TreeView of items, and a corresponding TreeViewModel. I want to support a property on the TreeViewModel which keeps a track of the currently selected item in the TreeView.

This is the code I have:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TreeMenuViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <common:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemsTemplate" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuOption}"/>
    </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit:DockPanel>
        <sdk:TreeView 
            Name="treeView1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Left"  
            Background="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemsTemplate}"                  
            >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction 
                         TargetObject="{Binding}" 
                         PropertyName="SelectedItemId" 
                         Value="{Binding MenuOptionId}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </sdk:TreeView>
    </toolkit:DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

The TreeView binds and displays the data correctly. The trigger is also working and targeting the correct property - when I break on the SelectedItemId property in the TreeViewModel, the property is being hit, but the value supplied is always 0. How can I supply the value of the selected item?

Comment: Why do (you think) you need a trigger? I think you can just bind SelectedItem to some property.

Comment: I'm new to Xaml - would you mind providing a snippet? Happy to accept as the answer if it works :)

Comment: Yeah why not just bind the SelectedItem to the property Tag. and cast it in the code behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the whole trigger and add:

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild}"
```

And then your ViewModel needs a SelectedChild property. Your VM can react to changes from the setter of that property.

If you want 2-way binding then make it a NotifyChange property.

And I think you want the id:  SelectedChild.Id or something like that.

Comment: +1 for the general approach but the comment on 2-way binding is misleading.  You need INotifyChanged on the VM (what VM doesn't?) so that the SelectedItem in the treeview reflects any change to the `SelectedChild` property.  However for the value of the `SelectedChild` to be modified by the user selecting a different node in the tree the `SelectedItem` binding should have Mode=TwoWay included.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `TreeView` `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` properties:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit:DockPanel>
        <sdk:TreeView 
            Name="treeView1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Left"  
            Background="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemsTemplate}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItemId, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedValuePath="MenuOptionId"
        />
    </toolkit:DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Throws an exception - 'Cannot set the readonly property SelectedValue'. Incidentally, I got that working using the trigger by referencing the treeview and the SelectedValue path...

Comment: Malcom: Thats a shame, not quite the same as other SelectedValue implementations.  Still its probably better you having `SelectedItem` property on your model than a `SelectedItemId`, although in other circumstances that can be awkward.

Comment: Yeah I can see what you were doing here (now :)), it's probably a quirk of the Treeview control. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

why not use something like this.

```
(SingleObjectInYourList)Item = treeview.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: I'm using MVVM, so the binding needs to be set in the XAML. All I need is a way of telling the ChangePropertyAction to use the item path MenuItem.MenuOptionId as the value to supply to the property. Shouldn't be hard?